# How to parse an expression using RegEx?

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to know if I can get what I want using RegEx with PowerShell or if I need to code a character per character parsing routine.

```
$TextToParse1 = "ONE = function(A,B,function(C,D),E);"      
# I would like to get the first function parameters in an array => $ParseParams = @('ONE','',('A','B','function(C,D)','E'))

$TextToParse2 = "TWO=Z:function(A,B,function(C,D),E,F,G);"  
# I would like to get the first function parameters in an array => $ParseParams = @('TWO','Z:',('A','B','function(C,D)','E','F','G'))

$TextToParse3 = @"
THREE = function(
    A,
    B,
    function(C,D),
    E);
"@
# I would like to get the first function parameters in an array => $ParseParams =@('THREE','',('A','B','function(C,D)','E'))

$TextToParse4 = @"
FOUR = function(
    A,
    B,
    function(
        C,
        D
    ),
    E);
"@
# I would like to get the first function parameters in an array => $ParseParams =@('FOUR','',('A','B','function(C,D)','E'))
```

Comment: Try reading about Abstract Syntax Tree in PowerShell (AST, like here [How To Use PowerShell's Abstract Syntax Tree To Your Advantage](https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-take-advantage-of-powershells-abstract-syntax-tree)

Comment: Since it looks like the arguments to your function call can be other function calls I doubt that a regular expression will suffice for parsing this.